# Mesh problems after dissolving vertices

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

After a pause of some years I am trying to learn Blender again. I created a loop cut in my mesh and dissolved half of the vertices. After that my mesh show a strange look. I have a  subdivision surface modifier added. I cannot see any strange things in edit mode.

This is mesh before dissolving the vertices.

[image]

And this is my mesh after dissolving the vertices

[image]

It has been a long time since I posted a question here. So I hope my question is correctly formulated.

Comment: Please include an image in Edit mode so that we can see the vertices.

Comment: When you dissolve vertices instead of deleting them, Blender keeps the connections between adjacent vertices as far as possible, so for example if you have a quarter circle and you dissolve all vertices building the curve except for the center and two outer vertices, you'll get a triangle, whereas deleting them would leave you with two edges building a right angle.

Comment: Gordon, you were right. Thanks